# After turning a react app into a PWD the url changes

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I have a react app that works on for example `http://localhost:3000/` after I add the config to make it a PWA the url change to `http://localhost:3000/my-app`.

Is this normal behaviour or is my config?

This is my worker.js

```
// /my-app/public/worker.js
let CACHE_NAME = "my-app";
let urlsToCache = ["/", "/completed"];
let self = this;

// Install a service worker
self.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
  // Perform install steps
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function (cache) {
      console.log("Opened cache");
      return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
    })
  );
});

// Cache and return requests
self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
      // Cache hit - return response
      if (response) {
        return response;
      }
      return fetch(event.request);
    })
  );
});

// Update a service worker
self.addEventListener("activate", (event) => {
  let cacheWhitelist = ["my-app"];
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then((cacheNames) => {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map((cacheName) => {
          if (cacheWhitelist.indexOf(cacheName) === -1) {
            return caches.delete(cacheName);
          }
        })
      );
    })
  );
});
```

This is my manifest.json

```
// /my-app/public/manifest.json
{
  "short_name": "My App",
  "name": "My App",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

This is the pachage.json

```
// /my-app/package.json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "http://<username>.github.io/my-app",
  "dependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried to change "my-app" in `worker.js`, and in `package.json` but that doesn't seem to change anything, maybe the config of that is in another place?

And now if I go to `http://localhost:3000/` I get a blank page and the error

```
bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
0.chunk.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
main.chunk.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
(index):39 Worker registration successful http://localhost:3000/
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
```

If this is not normal, how can I change it to just be `http://localhost:3000/` again?